# React Native Accessing view manager configs directly off UIManager via UIManager['AIRMap'] is no longer supported

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm getting the following warning "Accessing view manager configs directly off UIManager via UIManager['AIRMap'] is no longer supported. Use UIManager.getViewManagerConfig('AIRMap') instead". Its been showing since I have installed the react-native-maps package. Should I ignore it or its there a solution for it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19):

This is fixed by downgrading "react-native-gesture-handler" to 1.3.0. You also need to clear the cache or you'll continue to see the warning.

1. Modify your package.json:

`"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0"`

2. Reinstall dependencies:

`npm install` or `yarn install`

3. Restart expo with a clear cache:

`expo r -c`

Comment: Works perfect. Although, it's pretty frustrating that downgrading is the solution to an app-breaking error.

Comment: Using `expo install dependency-name-here` will ensure that the 'Expo-supported' version of the dependency is installed.

Answer (score 3):

To hide the warning, [downgrade](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6217) react-native-gesture-handler to ‘1.3.0’.

`yarn add react-native-gesture-handler@1.3.0`

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known issue with react-native 0.58 https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2620

Answer (score 1):

This is for those who want a quick fix, here are some commands that you can run to fix it. Remember this solution is for expo users.

```
// make sure you have the latest expo-cli (if you have >=3.1.0, you can skip this)
$ npm install -g expo@latest

// remove your node_modules and package-lock.json (just to be sure)
$ rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json

// check if you have `react-native-gesture-handler` listed already (if so **remove it**)
$ cat package.json | grep react-native-gesture-handler

// use expo to install the appropriate version
$ expo install react-native-gesture-handler

// start expo with a clean cache
$ expo start --clear
```

Answer (score 0):

you need just downgrade react-native-gesture-handler to 1.3.0.

also You can do these steps:

1. directly change version in your package.json to ~1.3.0
2. run npm i or remove it and install through expo
3. sometimes it needs to clear cache of expo > expo r -c

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **expo**, you can now use the command

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler
```

This will make sure nothing breaks by installing `react-native-gesture-handler` in version 1.3.0 instead of 1.5.x.
There is a [pretty recent issue on Github](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/742) discussing this.